# Is there a way to know whether the customer used the coupon code?

Tags: magento

I set the coupon code for my site, but only the register customer can use and use only once, is there a way to know whether  the customer used the coupon code? thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is a table `salesrule_customer` that contains all used rules, including coupons. In the field `times_used` you'll get your number for each customer.

To get the connection between `coupon` and `rule_id` open table `salesrule_coupon`.

To wrap it up, here's the query you should use:

```
SELECT sco.code, scu.customer_id, scu.times_used FROM salesrule_coupon sco
INNER JOIN salesrule_customer scu ON sco.rule_id = scu.rule_id
GROUP BY scu.customer_id;
```

If you want to filter your coupon code add `WHERE` part:

```
SELECT sco.code, scu.customer_id, scu.times_used FROM salesrule_coupon sco
INNER JOIN salesrule_customer scu ON sco.rule_id = scu.rule_id
WHERE sco.code='your_code'
GROUP BY scu.customer_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make a mysql table: `used_coupons`

And insert `username` and `coupon_code` everytime a coupon is used.

Then if a user enters a coupon code, just check if an entry exists. If entry exists, coupon is already used.

Comment: There's already exist a table named **salesrule_customer** to record the related information, no need to create new one.